# Kivy Python Error on KV File - Layout is not Triggered

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am new to both Python and Kivy, while I was trying out I got the following error, and browsed net but not able to find the issue, could you please explain my error in the below code:

Error:

```
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[WARNING           ] `<ui.LoginForm.LoginForm object at 0x02D503E8>` have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

Structure:

[image: File & Folder Structure]

File: Main.py

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from ui.LoginForm import LoginForm
    
    class MyApp(App):
            
        def build(self):
            c = LoginForm()
            return c
    
    if __name__ in ( '__main__','__android'):
        MyApp().run()

File: loginform.kv
<LoginForm>
    UserIDtxt: UserIDtxt
    rows: 2
    cols:2
    
    Label:
        text: 'User ID:'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '40dp'
        
    TextInput:
        id: UserIDtxt
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "40dp"
            
    Label:
        text: "User PW:"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "40dp"
        
    TextInput:
        id: "UserPWtxt"
        password: True
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "40dp"
```

File: LoginForm.py

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

class LoginForm(GridLayout):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Builder.load_file('ui/loginform.kv')
```

1. I tried with `Builder.load_file`, adding `UserIDtxt: UserIDtxt` to KV file is showing as error, could you please let me learn where my error is. Also, as per kivy specifications, it should load the KV file automatically if filename is same in small letters, why should I use a builder class again.
2. Also, I receive following log when I comment out `UserIDtxt: UserIDtxt` in KV file.

   [WARNING           ] `<ui.LoginForm.LoginForm object at 0x02DA9458>` have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.
   [INFO              ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...

Thank you.

[EDIT]:
All the things said by @inclement worked, thank you. I made the modifications as follows:

1. I added the my.kv file with same content as loginform.kv as it is, no change.
2. Removed build statement from `loginForm.py`:
   Then I receive the following: app no displaying again, could you please tell me how to add multiple class in KV file and get them to use in respective py files.

   [INFO              ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
   [WARNING           ] `<ui.LoginForm.LoginForm object at 0x02DB1420>` have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your load_file is in the wrong place (you don't actually see this error yet because of your other problems)

```
super(LoginForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
Builder.load_file('ui/loginform.kv')
```

Any kv file definitions for your widgets are applied during a widget's normal `__init__` method, which you call with super here. Since you only try to load the kv file *after* this would have happened, kivy doesn't know about your rules, so (as per the warning message) the layout isn't triggered.

You could put the `load_file` above the `super`, but even simpler would be to just load all your kv files at the start of your app (e.g. as the first thing during `build`) or put them in the default kv file as explained below. Performance implications will be minimal, you can change it later if it's important.

Edit: Maybe you misunderstood what the load does - it only loads the widget definitions from the kv file, it doesn't apply them to any widgets. That only happens when the widget is instantiated, which is why you need to load the file first.

---

2) Your `UserIDtxt` property shouldn't be uppercase

Kivy language uses the case of the first letter to determine if a line refers to a property or a child widget. In this case, it thinks it's a child widget (because widget class names should start with capital letters), so your syntax is wrong.

---

3) Your autoload question:

> Also, as per kivi specifications, it should load the kv file automatically if filename is same in small letters

Kivy will automatically try to load a *single* kv file with a name based on the lowercase form of your App class (without the App suffix if it exists). In this case, your app class is `MyApp`, so kivy will try to load `my.kv`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation, I edited the question at end, could you please enlighten me on that issue too.

Comment: I don't think that warning will crash the program. Is there no traceback displayed? Did you change as per my second point above?

Comment: sorry, a copy paste of wrong lines, the issue is "[WARNING           ] <ui.LoginForm.LoginForm object at 0x02DB1420> have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.", please advice on how to keep multiple classes in one file and how to access/load them form other py files.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, try making a new question that clearly states your actual problem, including the *full* log output (not just the small part you think is important)